# Eclipse market place not working. Shows error: resource not found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I have tried to change the network settings from direct to native to manual. I even tried a manual host but to no avail. I changed the eclipse.ini file as suggested in an answer on stack overflow, that did not work either.

Error: Resource not found: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=win32&ws=win32&nl=en_US&java.version=1.8.0_242&product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide&product.version=4.6.0.I20160606-1100&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.0.v20160606-1100
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.5.4.v20170222-1921&os=win32&ws=win32&nl=en_US&java.version=1.8.0_242&product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide&product.version=4.6.0.I20160606-1100&runtime.version=3.12.0.v20160606-1342&platform.version=4.6.0.v20160606-1100

However, I tried using the internal browser and it works. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFosG.png)

Comment: Hi Muhammad, please copy the error to your question instead of taking a screenshot of it, it will help people in the future with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse.org seems to be **slow at the moment** as you can see on the [Eclipse Status website](https://status.eclipse.org/). **Try again later**.

By the way, your Eclipse is pretty old. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).